# registerDoParallel in doParallel using Shiny

Tags: r, parallel-processing, shiny

Below is some pseudo code for a general question I think can be answered without a reproducible code. If I'm wrong and the reproducible code is needed, I will update my post.

I have a Shiny app that makes use of the **`dopar`** function from the **`doParallel`** package in R. In the server portion of my code, I have the first reactive expression that has a dependency on the action button "runScoring". When it executes, it runs `registerDoParallel` to register the parallel back end, as required.

Once the process generating a **`firstObject`** is done, it passes that result to a **`secondObject`** ( which depends on the same action button as the `firstObject` ) and then again runs the **`dopar`** function within the second reactive expression.

However, I only register the parallel back end within the first reactive expression and do not register it again within the second.

Is it necessary to place `registerDoParallel` within the second reactive expression in addition to having it within the first?

```
firstObject <- eventReactive(input$runScoring, {
        registerDoParallel(cores = input$cores4Scoring)
        itx1 <- iter(data1)
        itx2 <- iter(data2)
        result2 <- foreach(i = itx1, j = itx2, .export = funs) %dopar% {
        do stuff ...
        }
})

secondObject <- eventReactive(input$runScoring, {
        registerDoParallel(cores = input$cores4Scoring)
        itx1 <- iter(firstObject())
        result <- foreach(i = itx1 .export = funs) %dopar% {
        do stuff ...
        }
})
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear which environment the parallel backend is being called. It looks like the environment of `eventReactive` is `by default, the calling environment.` This suggests its the `server function` (ie parent) environment. But I think the answer is that **you do need to call `registerDoParalell` in each `eventReactive`**. Note that you use the var name `itx1` in each `eventReactive` but this is a different value. This suggests that each `eventReactive` environment is unique (and non-global). Thus, I think your cluster is lost after each `eventReactive`.